# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework.authentications'

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework

When I run `python manage.py migrate` command, I am having the following error:

```
ImportError: Could not import 'rest_framework.authentications.SessionAuthentiation' for API setting 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES'. 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework.authentications'.
```

Rest-framework-related parts of my code:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # 3rd party
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',

    # Local
    'posts.apps.PostsConfig',
]
```

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentications.SessionAuthentiation',
        'rest_framework.authentications.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
}
```

I am reading and going along with Django for APIs by W. S. Vincent.

Comment: Change `rest_framework.authentications` to `rest_framework.authentication`. Remove the trailing `s`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the documentation : https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#setting-the-authentication-scheme

It says :

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ]
}
```

Change `rest_framework.authentications` to `rest_framework.authentication` in your case. Remove the trailing `s`.